# C# excel interop process persists after crash

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have just recently started working with the Excel Interop in C# and have run into a problem with Excel processes persisting if my application crashes. (*Why* the process crashes is a separate issue that I am investigating.)

I *think* I am releasing the COM objects correctly as everything cleans up fine if my application completes successfully. It is only if it crashes or if I happen to quit during debugging that the Excel process is left.

Of course I realize when it crashes, the COM objects aren’t cleaned up. I am not sure how to handle this.

Here is a bit of pseudo-code that hopefully demonstrates what I am doing (the real code is rather long.)

It is supposed to 1)Open an existing excel file, 2) access a specific worksheet in the file, 3) insert a lot of rows, 4) add values to those rows, 5) close & save it all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    // Open excel file
    try {
        myExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        myExcelApp.Visible = false;
        myExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        myExcelWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook)myExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        string msg = "Error:Failed opening Excel File " + excelFile + ": " + ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }

    // ---- some other stuff here. ----

    foreach ( var toolWorkSheetName in workSheetsList ){

        // Init
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = null;
        Excel.Range xlRange = null;

        // Get specific worksheet from workbook
        try {
            xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[toolWorkSheetName];
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            string msg = "Error:Could not open worksheet in " + toolWorkSheetName + ": " + ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }

        // First scan existing template for insertion row & number of rows to insert
        xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        object[,] values = (object[,])xlRange.Value2;
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);  // Release local com objects 
        int colCount = values.GetLength(1);
        values = null;

        // ---- Determine the following: -----
        // insertRow =~ 3;
        // nLinesToInsert  =~ 63233;
        // colCount =~ 400;

        // Insert a range of rows for the values
        Excel.Range range = xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[insertRow, 1], xlWorksheet.Cells[insertRow + nLinesToInsert - 1, colCount]];
        range.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);

        values = new object[nLinesToInsert, colCount];

        // ---- populate the new values array ----

        // Insert the values at the target rows.
        Excel.Range startCell = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[insertRow, 1];
        Excel.Range endCell = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[insertRow + nCsvInsertRows - 1, nColsDo];
        Excel.Range writeRange = xlWorksheet.Range[startCell, endCell];
        writeRange.Value2 = values;
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(writeRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(endCell);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(startCell);

        // Release local com objects 
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

    }

    //cleanup (NB: Does this need to be done? Does it need to be done here?)
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    // Save
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    myExcelWorkbook.SaveAs(outFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, misValue,
                        misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                        misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

    myExcelWorkbook.Close();
    myExcelApp.Quit();

    //close and release
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelWorkbook);
    myExcelWorkbook = null;

    //quit and release
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelApp);
    myExcelApp = null;
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to use Excel interop? Could you get away with using a library capable of manipulating Excel files directly? I'm thinking of tools like EPPlus, NPIO, ClosedXML, Open XML SDK, Aspose etc. These often run much faster, with easier to understand error messages, and less likely to have weird COM issues.

Comment: @ mason That has been suggested an I intend to look into it. Anything to make life easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your try catch, you should be closing Excel. Like so

```
      try{
            //Some code
        }
    catch{
       Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
        myExcelWorkbook.Close();
         myExcelApp.Quit();

     }
```

As it stands when it fails it does not close Excel.

Comment: Oh heck. Pretty obvious now! Thanks.

Comment: @user1074069 Glad I could help, I overlook things like this all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing the object outside of `try-catch` blocs. And in the catch, you create a new exception even with a new message. When you are creating a new exception from catch block your original exception is gone. Considered as a bad practice.

You have to release objects inside the `catch` or `finally` blocks. According to your code, your objects are still persisted after the crash.

BTW, to work with Excel I would recommend the [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) library. It will perform all operation that you need without installing Excel on the server (bad practice again).

**UPDATE**

To clean-up all the objects:

```
           System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(startCell );    
           System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(endCell);             
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(writeRange);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange );
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange );
            startCell = null;
            endCell = null;
            writeRange = null;

            myExcelApp.Quit();

          System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelApp);
            myExcelApp = null;
            myExcelWorkbook = null;

            System.GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: Yeah, a pretty obvious mistake on my part. I'll look into the EPPlus library but I doubt it will be an option at my work. Thanks.

Comment: Re your UPDATE: Interestingly enough, simply releasing myExcelWorkbook and myExcelApp seems to be enough to get rid the stray object even though a few other Range objects are not released properly. I am a bit surprised as well.